# Модуль Numpy выдаёт ошибку при выводе tanh

Tags: python, math, numpy

Хочу реализовать Гиперболический тангенс на python(только заготовка , вывожу на экран результат для начала).

Вот код:

```
def mainFunc():

#try:
   if input() != "import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\x\\PycharmProjects\\MachineLearning', 'C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning'])":
        weightIQ = float(input("{+}Enter weight IQ\n[float]>>> "))
        weightFun = float(input("{+}Enter weight FUN\n[float]>>> "))
        weightMontage = float(input("{+}Enter weight MONTAGE\n[float]>>>"))
        equal_weight_iq = int(input("{+}Enter IQ\n[int]>>>")) * weightIQ
        equal_weight_fun = int(input("{+}Enter  FUN\n[int]>>>")) * weightFun
        equal_weight_montage = int(input("{+}Enter  MONTAGE\n[int]>>>")) * weightMontage
        sume = equal_weight_iq + equal_weight_fun + equal_weight_montage
        #activation2(equal_weight_iq,equal_weight_fun)
        #activation3(equal_weight_iq,equal_weight_fun,equal_weight_montage)
        #activation2(equal_weight_iq + equal_weight_fun + equal_weight_montage)
        #print(equal_weight_iq + equal_weight_fun + equal_weight_montage)
        #onefunc(equal_weight_iq + equal_weight_fun + equal_weight_montage)
        #print( 1/ (1 + 2.7 * (abs(1) * equal_weight_iq + equal_weight_fun + equal_weight_montage)))
        #secondfunc( 1/ (1 + 2.7 * (abs(1) * equal_weight_iq + equal_weight_fun + equal_weight_montage)))
        print(np.tanh(np.array([sume]),np.array([1])))
#except Exception:
   #print("Error!")
   #sys.exit()

mainFunc()
```

После ввода всех данных , появляется ошибка :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 37, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/FirstProgramm.py", line 97, in <module>
    mainFunc()
  File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/FirstProgramm.py", line 92, in mainFunc
    print(np.tanh(np.array([sume]),np.array([1])))
TypeError: ufunc 'tanh' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

**Почему** появляется ошибка , **как** её решить?

P.S. Вам может смутить этот код `if input() != "import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\x\\PycharmProjects\\MachineLearning', 'C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning'])"` . Не обращайте на него внимание , он никак не влияет на ошибку .

Comment: Какой тип у `sume` - `type(sume)`?

Comment: @MaxU float - тип данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.tanh()` ожидает в качестве первого аргумента массив (`array_like`) входных значений и в качестве второго (необязательного) переменную в которую запишутся значения.

В любом случае `np.tanh()` вернет результат - вне зависимости от того указан второй параметр или нет, поэтому обычно второй параметр не используется:

```
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.tanh(x)
```

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы вместо того чтобы передать `ndarray`/`list`/`tuple`/etc. (`array_like`) входных значений в качестве **первого параметра**, передали два параметра.

Решение - замените:

```
np.tanh(np.array([sume]),np.array([1]))
```

на:

```
np.tanh( ( np.array([sume]),np.array([1]) ) )
#        ^                                ^
```

Пример:

```
In [58]: sume = 0.5

In [59]: np.tanh( ( np.array([sume]),np.array([1]) ) )
Out[59]:
array([[ 0.46211716],
       [ 0.76159416]])
```

Но лучше передавать на вход один `NDArray`.

Например если на выходе нужна матрица размерности `(2,1)`:

```
In [60]: np.tanh(np.array([[sume], [1]]))
Out[60]:
array([[ 0.46211716],
       [ 0.76159416]])
```

если нужен вектор:

```
In [61]: np.tanh(np.array([sume, 1]))
Out[61]: array([ 0.46211716,  0.76159416])
```